# Long polling with PHP and jQuery - issue with update and delete

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I wrote a small script which uses the concept of long polling.

It works as follows:

- jQuery sends the request with some parameters (say lastId) to php
- PHP gets the latest id from database and compares with the lastId.
- If the lastId is smaller than the newly fetched Id, then it kills the
  script and echoes the **new** records.
- From jQuery, i display this output.

I have taken care of all security checks. The problem is when a record is deleted or updated, there is no way to know this.

The nearest solution i can get is to count the number of rows and match it with some saved row count variable. But then, if i have 1000 records, i have to echo out all the 1000 records which can be a big performance issue.

The CRUD functionality of this application is completely separated and runs in a different server. So i dont get to know which record was deleted.

**I don't need any help coding wise, but i am looking for some suggestion to make this work while updating and deleting.**

Please note, websockets(my fav) and node.js is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a certain ID from your table, you could also check when the table itself was modified the last time.

SQL:

```
SELECT UPDATE_TIME
FROM   information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdb'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';
```

If successful, the statement should return something like

```
UPDATE_TIME
2014-04-02 11:12:15
```

Then use the resulting timestamp instead of the `lastid`. I am using a very similar technique to display and auto-refresh logs, works like a charm.

You have to adjust the statement to your needs, and replace `yourdb` and `yourtable` with the values needed for your application. It also requires you to have access to [`information_schema.tables`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/tables-table.html), so check if this is available, too.

Two alternative solutions:

- If the solution described above is too imprecise for your purpose (it might lead to issues when the table is changed multiple times per second), you might combine that timestamp with your current mechanism with `lastid` to cover new inserts.
- Another way would be to implement a table, in which the current state is logged. This is where your ajax requests check the current state. Then generade [triggers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) in your data tables, which update this table.

Comment: Thanks @Bjoern, this looks like a very nice solution. I tried to execute the query changing the required fields, no error, but i get the UPDATE_TIME as null. Am i missing something ? I will try this from php script and intimate you.

Comment: From php script also its showing null. Do i need a specific type of table ?

Comment: The third option was in my mind and is easy to implement (its actually lil lengthy), but if the query you mentioned works for me, that would be really awesome.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha You have to adjust the statement to your needs, and replace `yourdb` and `yourtable` with the values needed for your application. It also requires you to have access to `information_schema.tables`, so check if this is available, too.

Comment: I wrote in my comment earlier "I tried to execute the query changing the required fields".

Comment: I am doing this in my localhost - wamp server. So yes, information_schema.tables is accessible.

Comment: @AbhishekSaha what happens if you execute this statement manually, p.e. via command line? Does the mysql server return `0`, too?

Comment: The query runs without any errors. Instead of UPDATE_TIME, i used * and printed the entire array. I then came across this link - http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=14374 which says that it works fine with innodb but not MyISAM.

Comment: I changed the table to innodb. But still it shows the UPTATE_TIME value as null. The CREATE_TIME is correctly showing. Then i created a new table. Still it didnt work. I am trying to create a new database to test this. Thanks for getting me here.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that this could be bugged. It works fine in my enviroments, and a few services rely heavily on that. If you're using MyISAM, you might even do this another way: just check the timestamp of your MyISAM files in your mysqls database folder instead. I wouldn't recommend that, but it should work nevertheless. IMO then the best solution would be to add triggers to your tables and let them write into a kind of management table, which you access for obtaining the status of last_changed.

Comment: Yes triggers would be the best way to deal with this. But i still liked the other solution you provided with the query. Thanks. Ticked your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest ID by

```
SELECT id FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1
```

but this is not reliable in my opinion, because you can have ID's of 1, 2, 3, 7 and you insert a new row having the ID 5.

**Keep in mind: the highest ID, is not necessarily the most recent row.**

The current auto increment value can be obtained by

```
SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'yourdb'
AND TABLE_NAME = 'yourtable';
```

Maybe a timestamp + microtime is an option for you?

Comment: But i update the table and change any column value, the auto_increment field will not help me.